# How to print the results of multiple loops in a single debug message in Ansible?

Tags: loops, ansible

I have a playbook that loops through a shell command for the values in a csv, modifies the results of the shell command with another loop and then prints them with a debug message.

I cannot seem to figure out how to output values from both loops into a single debug task.
The tasks doing the work of the playbook are:

```yaml
#get url certificate
- name: get url certificate
  become: false
  shell: echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername {{ loop_var_openssl_get_certificate_csv.url_base }} -connect {{ loop_var_openssl_get_certificate_csv.url_base }}:{{ loop_var_openssl_get_certificate_csv.url_port }} 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -inform pem -noout -text
  loop: "{{ register_read_csv.list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: loop_var_openssl_get_certificate_csv
  register: register_certificate

#extract cn from certificate
- name: extract cn from certificate
  set_fact:
    certificate_cn: "{{ item | regex_replace('\\s', '') | regex_search(regex_certificate_cn, '\\2') }}"
  loop: "{{ register_certificate.results }}"
  register: register_certificate_cn
  no_log: true
```

where the contents of my SCV are:

```
url_base,url_port
www.google.com,443
www.youtube.com,443
```

The first attempt at my debug message is looping through loop number 2, so I understand that I'm getting the entirety of loop 1's output, with the debug task looking like this sitting just below the `extract cn from certificate` task:

```yaml
#print detailed list
- name: print detailed list
  debug:
    msg: "{{ register_read_csv.list }},{{ item.ansible_facts}}"
  loop: "{{ register_certificate_cn.results }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.ansible_facts}}"
```

which outputs the following:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={'certificate_cn': ['www.google.com']}) =>
  msg:
  - - url_base: www.google.com
      url_port: '443'
    - url_base: www.youtube.com
      url_port: '443'
  - certificate_cn:
    - www.google.com
ok: [localhost] => (item={'certificate_cn': ['*.google.com']}) =>
  msg:
  - - url_base: www.google.com
      url_port: '443'
    - url_base: www.youtube.com
      url_port: '443'
  - certificate_cn:
    - '*.google.com'
```

In the end I would like the msg to read something like:

```
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - - url_base: www.google.com
      url_port: 443
      certificate_cn: www.google.com
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    - url_base: www.youtube.com
      url_port: 443
      certificate_cn: '*.google.com'
```

but I'm not quite sure how to get both loops' content to output how I'd like it to.

Answer (score 1):

You can always access the item that was used at the creation of a `results` set via the `item` property — or the name you gave in the `loop_var` parameter — of the items in `results`.

So, in your actual trial, you could do something like this (without the need of the `set_fact`):

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      {{ 
        item.loop_var_openssl_get_certificate_csv 
        | combine({
          'certificate_cn': item.stdout_lines 
          | select('contains', 'Subject: CN =')
          | first
          | replace('Subject: CN =', '')
          | trim
        }) 
      }}
  loop: "{{ register_certificate.results }}"
  loop_control:
    label: >-
      {{ item.loop_var_openssl_get_certificate_csv.url_base }}
      {{ item.loop_var_openssl_get_certificate_csv.url_port }}
```

---

This said, I would recommend you to reconsider your approach, as, feeding shell commands to Ansible, when there are dedicated modules doing what you need is not the good solution.

Here, the module [`community.crypto.get_certificate`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/crypto/get_certificate_module.html) is exactly what you need, and it formats the certificat information in a dictionary already, so you don't have to process the result of it.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - community.crypto.get_certificate:
        host: "{{ item.url_base }}"
        port: "{{ item.url_port }}"
      loop: "{{ urls }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.url_base }}:{{ item.url_port }}"
      register: register_certificate
      vars:
        urls:
          - url_base: www.google.com
            url_port: 443
          - url_base: www.youtube.com
            url_port: 443

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.item | combine({'certificate_cn': item.subject.CN}) }}"
      loop: "{{ register_certificate.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item.url_base }}:{{ item.item.url_port }}"
```

This yields the expected:

```
TASK [community.crypto.get_certificate] *************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=www.google.com:443)
ok: [localhost] => (item=www.youtube.com:443)

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=www.google.com:443) => 
  msg:
    certificate_cn: www.google.com
    url_base: www.google.com
    url_port: 443
ok: [localhost] => (item=www.youtube.com:443) => 
  msg:
    certificate_cn: '*.google.com'
    url_base: www.youtube.com
    url_port: 443
```